# Vestigialities: A word?

Tags: vocabulary

Is this an appropriate word to use? I did a quick google, and I'm only getting vague references.

Does the word 'Vestigialities' exist?

Comment: "He discussed with them their struggles with the vestigialities of the past, their breaking marriages. Barbara, large and yellow-haired, grew alive with expectation too; she began to push at the world." [Malcolm Bradbury, *The History Man*, 2011, p54 http://books.google.com/books?id=ZrkLi1UGo6YC&pg=PA54&dq=Vestigialities+-Vestigiality+-Vestigial&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ta9BUbjeCsv-rAeRnICwBQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term **vestigiality** is simply formed by placing the suffix *-ity* after the word *[vestigial](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vestigial?q=vestigial)*.

> **vestigial**
>
> forming a very small remnant of something that was once much larger or more noticeable: he felt a vestigial flicker of anger from last night.
>
> [Biology] (of an organ or part of the body) degenerate, rudimentary, or atrophied, having become functionless in the course of evolution: the vestigial wings of kiwis are entirely hidden.

It appears that **vestigiality** is not a count noun when it is used in a biological sense (as suggested by [a Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestigiality)).

However, when it is used in the normal sense, as suggested by [Kris](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14666/kris), it is countable.

> *Provided by [Kris](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/14666/kris)*:
>
> "*He discussed with them their struggles with the **vestigialities** of the past, their breaking marriages. Barbara, large and yellow-haired, grew alive with expectation too; she began to push at the world.*"
>
> [Malcolm Bradbury, [The History Man](http://books.google.com/books?id=ZrkLi1UGo6YC&pg=PA54&dq=Vestigialities%20-Vestigiality%20-Vestigial&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ta9BUbjeCsv-rAeRnICwBQ&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA%5D), 2011, p54]

Comment: If you also check the Wikipedia article on count nouns, you will also realise that the above article doesn't suggest that _vestigiality_ can have count-noun status (and thus doesn't address the question of whether or not the plural form _vestigialities_ is acceptable). Kris supplies a corroborative quote (though an Ngram search argues for its vanishingly small occurrence).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for point that out. I didn't notice that it is actually a question about count noun. At first sight I saw it as a simple word problem.